# Scanner error on readInt() while populating array of objects

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to iterate through an array of objects, and set one of their instance variables using a scanner. This is the code that's throwing an error:

```
 public void populate(){
    int participantID = 0;
    Scanner pop = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(participantID < participants.length){
        participants[participantID] = new Participant();
        System.out.println("Time in Seconds?");
        int time = pop.nextInt();
        participants[participantID].setTotalTime(time);
        participantID++;
    }
    pop.close();
}
```

Which is resulting in an error on the `int time = pop.nextInt();`line. Namely

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
Time in Seconds?    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
```

This is really confusing me as this method works fine:

```
    public void create(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the name of the triathlon?");
    raceName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("How many participants were there?");
    participants = new Participant[scan.nextInt()];

    scan.close();
}
```

---

Application.java

```
    public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Race mainRace = new Race();
        mainRace.create();
        System.out.println(mainRace.toString());
        mainRace.populate();
        System.out.println(mainRace.toString());
    }
}
```

Race.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Race {
    private String raceName;
    private Participant participants[];

    public Race(){

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Race{" +
                "raceName='" + raceName + '\'' +
                ", participants=" + participants.length +
                '}';
    }

    public void create(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(Colours.getAnsiYellow() + "What is the name of the triathlon?" + Colours.getAnsiReset());
        raceName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println(Colours.getAnsiYellow() + "How many participants were there?" + Colours.getAnsiReset());
        participants = new Participant[scan.nextInt()];

        scan.close();
    }

    public void populate(){
        int participantID = 0;
        Scanner pop = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(participantID < participants.length){
            participants[participantID] = new Participant();

            System.out.println(Colours.getAnsiYellow() + "Time in Seconds?" + Colours.getAnsiReset());
            int time = pop.nextInt();
            participants[participantID].setTotalTime(time);
            System.out.println(participants[participantID]);
            participantID++;

        }
        pop.close();

    }

}
```

Participant.java

```
public class Participant {
    private int id;
    private int runTime;
    private int swimTime;
    private int bikeTime;
    private int totalTime;

    public Participant(){
    }

    public int getTotalTime() {
        return totalTime;
    }

    public void setTotalTime(int totalTime) {
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }
}
```

Colours.java

```
public class Colours {
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";

    public static String getAnsiReset() {
        return ANSI_RESET;
    }


    public static String getAnsiYellow() {
        return ANSI_YELLOW;
    }

}
```

Comment: You will have to show us more of your program. I tried it out assuming an own Participant class and main method and it worked.

Comment: @TheQuestioner I've added the 4 classes the program consists of in the OP - would really appreciate it if you could have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your `populate` method. The problem is that your `Participant` array that you create inside the `create` method will not be around anymore after you close the Scanner. So call the `populate` method inside your `create` method instead of in your `Application` class.

`main`:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Race mainRace = new Race();
        mainRace.create();
        System.out.println(mainRace.toString());
    }
}
```

`create` method:

```
public void create() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(Colours.getAnsiYellow() + "What is the name of the triathlon?" + Colours.getAnsiReset());
    raceName = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(Colours.getAnsiYellow() + "How many participants were there?" + Colours.getAnsiReset());
    participants = new Participant[scan.nextInt()];

    populate(); 

    scan.close();


}
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped me perfectly. Appreciate the time!